# Converting matrix of radio buttons to a numerical value or percentage

Tags: jquery, html, jscript

I have three rows of radio buttons and each row belong to a group. User select one in each row and based on the selection the value should appear on the last column (1 st radio button has value 2, second is 1 and third is 0 and same for three rows) and hence the total of all rows at the end.

I used the following script to calculate the total. I am able to do for one row but not able to apply for each and then find the total.

When I tried to and plan to repeat for three, I am not able to get each column. Some could help me please?

```js
$(":radio").on("change", function() {
  var total = 0;
  $(":radio:checked").each(function() {
    total += Number(this.value);
  });

  $("#total").text(total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Vaules</td>
      <td>Good</td>
      <td>Better</td>
      <td>Poor</td>
      <td>Value selected</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quality</td>
      <td>
        <input id="defaultInline1" class="custom-control-input" name="Radio1" type="radio" />
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultInline1">&nbsp;</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultInline1">&nbsp;</label>
        <input id="defaultInline2" class="custom-control-input" name="Radio1" type="radio" />&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultInline2">&nbsp;</label>
        <input id="defaultInline3" class="custom-control-input" name="Radio1" type="radio" />&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <input name="total" type="text" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Taste</td>
      <td>
        <input id="defaultInline1" class="custom-control-input" name="Radio2" type="radio" />
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultInline1">&nbsp;</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultInline1">&nbsp;</label>
        <input id="defaultInline2" class="custom-control-input" name="Radio2" type="radio" />&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultInline2">&nbsp;</label>
        <input id="defaultInline3" class="custom-control-input" name="Radio2" type="radio" />&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <input name="total2" type="text" />
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quality</td>
      <td>
        <input id="defaultInline1" class="custom-control-input" name="Radio3" type="radio" />
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultInline1">&nbsp;</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultInline1">&nbsp;</label>
        <input id="defaultInline2" class="custom-control-input" name="Radio3" type="radio" />
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultInline2">&nbsp;</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultInline2">&nbsp;</label>
        <input id="defaultInline3" class="custom-control-input" name="Radio3" type="radio" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="total3" type="text" />
      </td>/td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Total</td>
      <td>
        <input name="ftotal" type="text" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the full code: https://jsfiddle.net/doctsh123/rLcnomst/6/

Comment: 2 things I noticed: You are using the same IDs on the radio buttons for each row, that is invalid HTML and can cause problems, IDs have to be unique. Secondly, your radion buttons don't have a `value` atribute on your example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's several issues in your HTML and JS:

- You have lots of duplicate `id` attributes. If you want to group elements, use `class` attributes instead. In this case you don't need them, though, so they can be removed.
- You've got some broken `/td>` tags which need to be removed
- The radio inputs have no `value` attribute to read, so these need to be added
- The empty `label` elements are redundant and can be removed
- To set the value of an input use `val()` not `text()`
- To set the value in the row, use `closest()` to get the `tr` then `find()` the input from there. A common class on all the inputs will make this easier.

With all that fixed, try this:

```js
$(":radio").on("change", function() {
  var total = 0;
  $(":radio:checked").each(function() {
    total += Number(this.value);
  });
  $("#total").val(total);
  
 $(this).closest('tr').find('.rowtotal').val(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Vaules</td>
      <td>Good</td>
      <td>Better</td>
      <td>Poor</td>
      <td>Value selected</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quality</td>
      <td><input class="custom-control-input" name="Radio1" type="radio" value="2" /></td>
      <td><input class="custom-control-input" name="Radio1" type="radio" value="1" /></td>
      <td><input class="custom-control-input" name="Radio1" type="radio" value="0" /></td>
      <td><input name="total" type="text" class="rowtotal" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Taste</td>
      <td><input class="custom-control-input" name="Radio2" type="radio" value="2" /></td>
      <td><input class="custom-control-input" name="Radio2" type="radio" value="1" /></td>
      <td><input class="custom-control-input" name="Radio2" type="radio" value="0" /></td>
      <td><input name="total2" type="text" class="rowtotal" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quality</td>
      <td><input class="custom-control-input" name="Radio3" type="radio" value="2" /></td>
      <td><input class="custom-control-input" name="Radio3" type="radio" value="1" /></td>
      <td><input class="custom-control-input" name="Radio3" type="radio" value="0" /></td>
     <td><input name="total3" type="text" class="rowtotal" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3"></td>
      <td>Total</td>
      <td><input name="ftotal" type="text" id="total" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```